# Seek method of just_audio is not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-seekbar, just-audio

I have Implemented audio player in my application using just_audio library. currently I'm facing the problem that is I have put one slider to seek audio and play at specific time duration, So when try to seek slider in backwards side it gives following error but while seek to forward it is working fine.

```
Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 0
```

Here is the code for that

```
Consumer<PlayerStateModel>(
  builder: (context, playerState, child) {
    return Slider(
      value: playerState.currentPosition.inSeconds.toDouble(),
      min: 0.0,
      max: playerState.duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
      inactiveColor: globals.shadowColor,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        final clampedValue = newValue.clamp(_value, playerState.duration.inSeconds.toDouble());
        debugPrint("CLAMPED VALUE $clampedValue");
        audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: clampedValue.toInt()));
        setState(() {
          _value = clampedValue;
        });
      },
    );
   },
  )
```

Comment: What OS? What audio file format? E.g. Are you using an audio file format that supports seeking?

Comment: Android 13, mp3 and wave (right now), no specific audio format is not matter to seeking audio it is working on every audio.

Comment: The audio format is precisely one of the main factors that can cause seeking issues. mp3 should be fine, mpeg-ts will probably not allow you to seek. just_audio comes with an example app that demonstrates seek works on mp3 files. So if you download that example and replace its mp3 with your mp3, you can test if it's a problem with your mp3 file.

Comment: But before for the same audio it was working fine. and audio format is mp3

Comment: Your sample code doesn't tell us what `playerState.duration` is, but assuming it is positive, your code doesn't allow seeking backwards anyway so I'm not sure what the point of your question is. If you clamped the value to prevent the user from seeking backwards, then that code is not helpful to your question and you should be showing the code that actually allows you to seek backwards in order to produce the error. Anyway, I pointed you at the official example which works, although you didn't get back to me on whether you tried it.